# How to format h3 element in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<tr>
    <td><h3>Support Group:<%= supportGroup %></h3></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to format the h3 element so that it displays on a straight line. Currently it shows as stacked

Comment: `white-space:pre` perhaps …?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean displaying it inline rather than block?

```
h3 { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    h3 {
    display:inline;    
    }
```

The display inline property would make the text display inline, however I believe your problem is more than likely being caused by the size of your table cell being too small to accompany the data inside it, which could be why you are experiencing this problem. What's the CSS for your table like, if you have any? And not that it's any of my business, but from what it seems... would "Support Group" not be better off as a table header? Such as...

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Support Group</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><%= supportGroup %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

However the widths of your cells, of your table, and your page, are all going to impact on the way your information is displayed.

Comment: I don't actually have any css. I believe you are correct in that the table cell may be too small. I do have bootstrap div table-responsive surrounding it

Comment: @user4200771 How large is the data of support group and how many other cells are there in the one row?

Comment: Support Group:EEE-EEE-EEEEEEEEE-EEEE
That's one example but it can vary. 12 cells in one row

Comment: If I adjust the size of the window it re-formats. When the browser window on a computer is maximized it shows stacked. When the browser window is shrunk down it will show on one line

Comment: @user4200771 I have tried to replicate your problem, however I encountered the adverse of your problem, and by nature of responsive design, when my browser was maximized I was able to see the content without it stacking. I'm not sure why you would see it on one line when minimized. I'm not sure I'm going to be able to help you but I did make you this [link](http://pastebin.com/v57ALtZm), it may be of help to you, and help you on the track to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if we're talking about bootstrap why use table?
try this:

```
 <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-12'>
     <h3>Support Group:<%= supportGroup %></h3>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[check bootstrap documentation on the grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)